# Installing pyreadline on portable python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I recently got portable python 2.7.6.1 from [here](http://portablepython.com/wiki/Download/)

I need to install pyreadline to this

I downloaded pyreadline zip file from https://pypi.org/project/pyreadline/#files

Is this zip file enough to get pyreadline installed in potable python? I don't have prior experience with python but I have read other posts about people trying to install modules to portable python so I am guessing it should be possible

I tried installing pip using `easy_setup pip` on the command prompt but I get the following error:

```
Searching for pip
Reading http://pypi.python.org/simple/pip/
Couldn't find index page for 'pip' (maybe misspelled?)
Scanning index of all packages (this may take a while)
Reading http://pypi.python.org/simple/
No local packages or download links found for pip
Best match: None
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\data_aba\python files\python_portable_2761\App\Scripts\easy_install-script.py", line 8, in <module>
    load_entry_point('setuptools==0.6c11', 'console_scripts', 'easy_install')()
  File "D:\data_aba\python files\python_portable_2761\App\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line 1712, in main
    with_ei_usage(lambda:
  File "D:\data_aba\python files\python_portable_2761\App\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line 1700, in with_ei_usage
    return f()
  File "D:\data_aba\python files\python_portable_2761\App\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line 1716, in <lambda>
    distclass=DistributionWithoutHelpCommands, **kw
  File "D:\data_aba\python files\python_portable_2761\App\lib\distutils\core.py", line 152, in setup
    dist.run_commands()
  File "D:\data_aba\python files\python_portable_2761\App\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 953, in run_commands
    self.run_command(cmd)
  File "D:\data_aba\python files\python_portable_2761\App\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 972, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "D:\data_aba\python files\python_portable_2761\App\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line 211, in run
    self.easy_install(spec, not self.no_deps)
  File "D:\data_aba\python files\python_portable_2761\App\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line 434, in easy_install
    self.local_index
  File "D:\data_aba\python files\python_portable_2761\App\lib\site-packages\setuptools\package_index.py", line 475, in fetch_distribution
    return dist.clone(location=self.download(dist.location, tmpdir))
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'clone'
```

Is there any way to install pyreadline from the contents of the zip file, or at least get pip installed so that I can use it to search for pyreadline?

EDIT 1 ---

I went to https://pypi.org/simple/pip/ and downloaded [pip-18.0.tar.gz](https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/69/81/52b68d0a4de760a2f1979b0931ba7889202f302072cc7a0d614211bc7579/pip-18.0.tar.gz#sha256=a0e11645ee37c90b40c46d607070c4fd583e2cd46231b1c06e389c5e814eed76). Is there any way I can install this manually from this zip file? But then again if that was possible, I assume it should be possible to just install pyreadline directly? How can I do this manunaly?